How to convert interface to discriminated union?
I am trying to convert simple interface to discriminated union type but there is some problem with the union type property. Here is a basic example. The whole code can be found here.
The type property is the same but I get:

Types of property 'type' are incompatible.

enum MessageTypes {
    Text = 1,
    Media,
    AccessRequest,
}

Convert this
interface MessageApiResponse {
    id: number
    type: MessageTypes
    content: string | MediaContentApiResponse | AccessRequestContentApiResponse
    chat_id: number
}

interface MediaContentApiResponse {
    mime_type: string,
    url: string
}

interface AccessRequestContentApiResponse {
    sender: User
    receiver: User
    status: AccessRequestContentStatuses
}

to this
type MessageBase = Omit<MessageEntityCache, "type" | "content"> & {
    isAuthor: boolean
};

interface MessageText {
    type: MessageTypes.Text
    content: string
}

interface MessageAccessRequestAuthor {
    type: MessageTypes.AccessRequest
    content: AccessRequestContentAuthor
    isAuthor: true
}

interface MessageAccessRequestNotAuthor {
    type: MessageTypes.AccessRequest
    content: AccessRequestContentNotAuthor
    isAuthor: false
}

type MessageAccessRequest = MessageAccessRequestAuthor | MessageAccessRequestNotAuthor

interface MessageMedia {
    type: MessageTypes.Media;
    content: MediaContentEntityCache;
}

type Message = MessageBase & (MessageText | MessageAccessRequest | MessageMedia);


Welcome to SO! The whole code needs to be included here as plaintext, not just as a playground link. Otherwise it doesn't count as a [mre] and the question risks being closed as needing debugging details. It also encourages people to minimize their examples, rather than just linking externally to some large amount of code. Almost every good [mre] for a SO question can fit on a single screen of normal-sized text at once without scrolling. Please [edit] to fix this.

See prev comment. While you're [edit]ing this, consider making the question clearer. Right now you say you want to "convert" an interface to a union. But that could mean either that you want a type function which takes in an interface and outputs a union type F<T> = ..., or you want a JS function which takes in a value of the interface type and outputs a value of the union type. Or maybe you could mean something else. Presumably the playground link makes this clear, but again, that doesn't suffice here.
